Question about usage of だ and ええがのう

むかしむかし、びんぼうなじいさまとばあさまがなかよくくらしていました。ある年の大みそかのこと。じいさまはため息をついていました。「はぁー。明日はお正月だというのに、おもちをつく米もない。なんぞうるもんでもあればええがのう」。


明日はお正月だというの: Is the だ here just for emphasis?

What is ええがのう. Does it means いいだろう here? "Even if we are able to sell anything that would be good eh?"




だ is basically required in this sentence. と is a quotative particle, and it normally takes a complete sentence ending with だ, した, etc. Actually, you can omit this だ (known as だ抜き), but you should not do so in formal text.

ええがのう is made of the following:

ええ (dialectal variant of いい = "good")
が ("but")
のう (sentence-end particle の, dialectal な, elongated for emphasis)

So it's equivalent to いいがな or いいけどな in modern Japanese. The literal translation of なんぞうるもんでもあればええがのう would be "If I have something to sell, it's good, but...".


